# Could you explain the sentence "we are words that feint dart and wheel like birds"?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

> we are words that feint dart and wheel like birds ([source](https://www.npr.org/2021/10/11/1045084711/encore-book-expresses-still-fresh-feelings-about-a-tumultuous-year))

I couldn't make out exactly what the author means by that particular sentence. Can someone explain?

Comment: There should have been a comma between "feint" and "dart". Dunno if that helps you understand it. If not, look up "feint", "dart" and "wheel" in a dictionary and see if any of the definition describe something birds might do.

Comment: Yes, it's all clear now. Thanks. Previously I thought "faint dart" is one verb+object clause and "wheel like birds" is another, connected by "and".

Answer (score 3):

I believe that this transcript is missing a comma. I think it should be:

> We are words that feint, dart and wheel like birds.

It is a poetic expression, so the meaning is up for interpretation, but the comparison is to the physical actions of birds (feinting, darting, and wheeling).

Comment: Another transcript has it with the commas:  *words that feint, dart, and wheel like birds*. https://onbeing.org/programs/tracy-k-smith-and-michael-kleber-diggs-history-is-upon-us-its-hand-against-our-back/